# Html Image map generator with custom shape

Tags: html, image, dictionary, generator

I'm looking for a tool which could help me with html map tag. I know I can do it by myself with photoshop and notepad, but it's very laborious. I've investigated image-maps.com but it scales up my image, so the coordinates I put won't fit to my website. Do you know an alternative tools?

Regards, 
David

Comment: I'm not sure of this, but I think that the `Image/Map Coordinates` option on [image-maps.com](http://www.image-maps.com) deals with potential scaling issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dreamweaver.
http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html